# Auto completion not work for command 'du'

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Autocompletion have been not working some days on my Mac.

If I comment the **compinit** part in zsh script, auto completions works for 'du' command, else it does not work.

I thought it may be caused by problem of my mac pro until I got a new mac pro. I installed on-my-zsh, and find that completion for 'du' still not work.

Comment: Have you tried `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit` ?

Comment: I've tried autoload -Uz compinit && compinit, completion for 'du' does not work. Does it works on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is known to be broken in the zsh version shipped in OSX 10.11. Newer zsh releases appear to contain a fix for non-GNU du utilities.

A workaround may be to install GNU coreutils and alias du=gdu

Another workaround could be to build and install a newer zsh locally (for example via homebrew).

See also https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/4573#issuecomment-153439901